# ¿Cómo obtener el GUID del usuario creado en GAM en tiempo real?

Tags: genexus

Tengo una tabla de Usuarios, donde almaceno los mismos usuarios creados en GAM.

La idea es que al registrar un usuario en GAM, se cree el registro en mi tabla. Entonces, la necesidad es poder obtener el GUID del usuario que se creó en el momento del alta.

Como casi todas las funciones de la API de GAM obtienen los datos del Usuario conectado, como solución se me ocurría lo siguiente: obtener toda la lista de usuarios y buscar por el nombre el usuario dado de alta y así obtener el GUID generado para darlo de alta en mi tabla.

Encontré un post que obtiene la lista de los usuarios dados de alta pero no me esta funcionando:

```
// Carga Usuarios de GAM 
//
&UserID.SetEmpty()

&GAMUser = &GamRepository.GetUsers(&GamUserFilter, &GamError)
For &GamUserItem in &GAMUser 
    If &GamUserItem.Name = &UserName
        &UserID = &GAMUserItem.GUID
        Exit
    EndIf
Endfor
```

Este código me da el siguiente error de compilación:

> error spc0010: Type mismatch in assignment: &GAMUser =
>   &GamRepository.getusers(&GamUserFilter,&GamError)
>   (GAMUserCollection.GAMUserCollectionItem Collection=GAMUser
>   Collection).

Las variables están definidas así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me puedo dar cuenta del error de tipos.

Comment: Haber, hasta done entiendo tienes una tabla de usuarios creada x ti y las tablas del GAM mismo vdd?

Answer (score 1):

El error de tipos es porque la función `GAMRepository.GetUsers()` no devuelve un `GAMUserCollection`, sino que devuelve una colección de `GAMUser`...

Es decir, en la definición de la variable `&GAMUser`, tiene que tener `Type = GAMUser` y el check `Is Collection` marcado. De hecho el nombre de la variable debería ser `&GAMUsers` o `&GAMUserCollection`, si no no queda claro que es una colección.

De todas formas, en GAMRepository hay otra función que tal vez te sirva más: `GetUserByLogin`, a la cual se le pasa el nombre de usuario...

Comment: Marcos, muchas gracias por los comentarios.. voy a probar cambiar la definición .. además probaré la función GetUserByLogin.. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso tenés que usar [GamUser](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22082,GAM%20Users)

Para obtener el GUID de quien está logueado proba con:

```
GamUser.GetId()
```

Yo en general uso:

```
GamUser.GetName()
```

para guardar en mi tabla de usuario como clave. Me resulta mas legible a nivel de datos y no admito 2 usuarios con el mismo Name.

Comment: Gracias Bruno por tus comentarios.. el problema es que necesito obtener el nombre del usuario que aún no se  a logueado, sino del usuario que se esta dando de alta que por consiguiente no se ha logueado. Es válido tu comentario de guardar en tu table el Name del usuario y no permitir duplicados, ya lo he pensado, pero bueno, la idea era ir por el GUID si era posible.. Marcos aporte algunos comentarios interesantes que probare... Sds.

Answer (score -1):

Si lo estas dando de alta y conoces el username, lo que puedes hacer es recuperarlo inmediatamente despues de grabarlo, es decir:

- Grabas el usuario...
- Luego con `GetUserByLogin`  obtienes una variable de tipo `GAMUser`, que contiene el usuario creado

Alli dispones del `&GAMUser.GetId()`